# How to get the height of a UIView without navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to add a UIWebView inside a clean UIViewController which in my Storyboard is embedded in a Navigation Controller:

```
UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds)];
webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

The problem is, that the self.view.bounds.size.height is 460, which seems to be the height of the entire view including the navigation bar. I could subtract the value of self.view.frame.origin.y which is 20 and get the desired hight of 440, but are there a more common way to do this?

**EDIT**

Please take a look at my small code example here: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/WebViewTest.zip

When you scroll down to the bottom of the UIWebView, the last part of the web site is not shown, as the webView is to high.

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Does **[self addSubview:webView];** actually compile? is it in the view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Setting the `autoresizingMask` in the UIWebView solved my problem:

self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: This worked for me. As a side note, I think another solution is to set the frame in viewWillAppear, as the view frame is not guaranteed to be correct in viewDidLoad or earlier

Answer (score 0):

Default height is 480, 460 - height without status bar. 44px - height of navigation bar (you can access to height since it's a UIView - navBar.frame.size.height). So, your view height is 480-20-44 = 416. And you need to subtract from `self.view.frame.size.height`, not `origin.y`

Comment: Unless it's landscape on the iphone. Then it's 34px tall.

Comment: @DHamrick, Then initial height will 320px :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. The navigation controller takes care of resizing the `view` of the view controller under its jurisdiction. You would only override this view's frame if you would like it to be e.g. smaller to fit other subviews onto its superview.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a better solution other than using `topLayoutGuide` (and optionally `bottomLayoutGuide`).

That is, adding your view to the controller's `self.view` and setting these constraints:

```
"H:|[view]|"
"V:[top][view][bottom]"
```

Where `top` is `self.topLayoutGuide` and `bottom` is `self.bottomLayoutGuide`.

As an example, see the `configureViewController:fillWithSubView:` method in [AutolayoutHelper](https://github.com/fmaylinch/autolayout-helper/blob/master/AutolayoutHelper.m).